# What is the final temperature of each substance upon absorbing 2.25 kJ of heat?

Tags: physical-chemistry, heat

> Suppose that $\pu{28 g}$ of silver is initially at $\pu{29.0^\circ C}$. What is its temperature upon absorbing $\pu{2.25 kJ}$ of heat?

My work: $2250 = 0.240 \times 28 \times t - 29$

Solve for $t$ and I get $\pu{340 ^\circ C}$. But the correct answer is $\pu{370 ^\circ C}$ and I have no clue how to get there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost correct, however, to calculate these values you need to put a bracket around he $t-29$ term (which is the $\Delta T$ term from $Q = mc \Delta T$). Hence, from your working out step:

$$2250 = 0.240 \times 28 \times (t - 29)$$

You'll need to expand the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

$\pu{2250 J} = \pu{28.0 g} \times 0.240 \times (T_\text{final} - \pu{29^\circ C})$ [$q = mC_\mathrm{s}\Delta T$]

1. Convert kJ to J as $\pu{2.25 kJ} \times 1000 = \pu{2250 J}$
2. The 0.240 is the specific heat capacity for silver (will most times be given to you)
3. The m is given
4. $\Delta T = T_\text{final} - T_\text{initial}$; We have T initial so plug in
5. Do the math. :)